# Dropdown Bootstrap 4 doesn't work in production of angular's application

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular8

I am using bootstrap 4 in my angular application, the dropdown function is working perfectly in mode developer but in production mode, I got this error:

> Uncaught Error: DROPDOWN: Option "popperConfig" provided type "window"
>   but expected type "(null|object)".
>       at Object.typeCheckConfig (vendors.e5434761d9d5f5d91054.bundle.js:1)
>       at e.t._getConfig (vendors.e5434761d9d5f5d91054.bundle.js:1)
>       at new e (vendors.e5434761d9d5f5d91054.bundle.js:1)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (vendors.e5434761d9d5f5d91054.bundle.js:1)

and this is the code that i'am using in my application

```
<div class="dropdown">

  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
    id="dropdown-search" data-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

    Fiches consultées
  </button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-filter filter-menu" 
    aria-labelledby="dropdown-search">

    <div *ngFor="let h of historiques" class="form-check">

      <input class="form-check-input" id="{{h.name}}" type="checkbox"
        value="{{h.name}}" [(ngModel)]="h.selected" 
        (change)="getSelected()">

      <label class="form-check-label" for="{{h.name}}">
        {{h.code}}
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is with bootstrap 4.4+ version, change to bootstrap 4.3.1 and will works fine.

You can install it from npm and then add the path into angular.json file (styles and scripts configs):

```
npm install bootstrap@4.3.1
```

or use urls in your index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this worked for my case. I downgraded the version to 4.3.1

Comment: You may not downgrade any more. Fixed in 4.5.0 (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/30383)

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue at the moment, but only with IE11.

Update 1:
As of right now I can tell you, that it hast something to do with the angular / typescript version. I reverted our app from 8.2.14 / 3.5.3 back to 8.0.0 / 3.4.3 and it starts working again. Now we will go up the different version to find out, what version change cases the problem.

Update 2:
After testing multiple combinations of angular versions, we found out that these two packages caused our problem:

"@angular-devkit/build-angular"

"@angular/cli"

A newly created angular 8 project uses the follwing versions:

"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~**0.803.20**"

"@angular/cli": "~**8.3.20**"

But with 8.3.x it´s not working! Reverting these two packages to the latest 8.2.x version fixes our problem!

"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "**0.802.2**"

"@angular/cli": "**8.2.2**"

Comment: This didn't work for me either. There is an opened issue about this in Github, but is currently closed waiting for a repro. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/29996

Comment: Did anybody get something on this?  I can't easily revert my versions due to other dependencies; I get the problem in electron but I'm not sure how easy it would be to make a reduced test case as there are a hell of a lot of dependencies!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too and fixed by replacing 2 occurrences of "popperConfig: (null|object)" for "popperConfig: {}" on bootstrap-4.4.1.js